# How to contribute to HSA with after-tax income and regain taxes paid?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, hsa, payroll

The payroll department screwed up at my company and didn't withdraw the final HSA contribution from my check for the purpose of depositing it into my HSA account. Their solution: just deposit into your HSA from your checking account.

This means I will be not gaining the advantage of a withdraw of pre-tax dollars. Is there a way to reconcile this such that I can regain taxes paid after contributing to an HSA from a checking account?

Answer (score 5):

When you file your taxes, the contribution will count as a deduction, so it is effectively pre-tax (talking about *federal income taxes*, which is the typical understanding of 'pre-tax').

What it doesn't give you back is the payroll tax you paid on the amount - Social Security 6.2% and Medicare 1.45% - those are gone.

In other words: an HSA contribution through direct payroll deduction into your HSA bypasses federal tax, Social Security, and Medicare contributions - a contribution from you results only in no federal tax. Still, this is normally the biggest part.

Comment: Make sure that the deposit is assigned to the correct year.

Comment: Im a bit confused because you say it is, "a deduction ... effectively pre-tax" but you also say that I wont get back the payroll tax I paid. If the former is true, I would expect that for my 2020 tax returns, I would get a refund for the taxes I paid. If the latter is true, I wouldn't expect to get that back. Sorry, just confused, it seems like conflicting statements from what I understand.

Comment: @8protons Payroll taxes and income taxes are not the same. They are two separate taxes. If your contribution to your HSA is done through your employer, you save on both, payroll and income taxes. If you make the contribution on your own, outside of your employer, then you only save on income taxes through a tax deduction when you file your taxes.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but $3600*7.65% is $275, which is a nice bit of money that I would like to not miss out on. This is unfortunate.

Comment: @MichaelA that's true in general for why it's better to contribute through your employer. Fortunately in this case it's only the last payment of the year, so maybe only 1/24th ($11) lost because of the mistake. (Even less if paid every 2 weeks, or weekly.)

Comment: @MichaelA , you can try to convince your employer to correct it, but it's work for them. Otherwise, that part is gone-gone. There is no mechanism to get it back except a correction through your employer.

Comment: Thanks (to both TTT and Aganju). I doubt they'll correct it looking back but maybe in 2021 and beyond they'll fix it.

Comment: @TTT this is a relatively new employer, didn't have an HSA previously, so there were four paychecks left in the year in which I was to max out my paycheck. That is, $887.50 was to be the final deposit to my HSA. So its a fair bit of taxation Im incurring now.

Comment: @8protons in that case you won't save the approx $70 in payroll taxes, but you'll still save the hundreds in federal (and state if applicable) by putting the money into the account yourself.